# Greenplum gprestore - cannot find file (gpfmt_gpss.so)

Tags: greenplum, rhel7, database-restore

I'm performing a **gprestore** on Linux RHEL 7 and I'm getting the following error:

> Greenplum Database Restore Report
>
> timestamp key:           20231207163727
>
> gpdb version:            6.25.3 build commit:367edc6b4dfd909fe38fc288ade9e294d74e3f9a Open Source
>
> gprestore version:       1.30.3
>
> database name:           *Not Applicable*
>
> command line:            gprestore --backup-dir /data/backup/ --timestamp 20231207163727
>
> backup segment count:    8
>
> restore segment count:   8
>
> start time:              Tue Jan 16 2024 16:21:49
>
> end time:                Tue Jan 16 2024 16:21:50
>
> duration:                0:00:01
>
> restore status:          Failure
>
> restore error:           **ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/gpfmt_gpss.so": No such file or directory (SQLSTATE 58P01)**

Below is what I could find on the error code:

> Class 58 — System Error (errors external to PostgreSQL itself)
>
> 58000 system_error
>
> 58030 io_error
>
> **58P01   undefined_file**

When searching for the filename (gpfmt_gpss.so) in question I do not find any details.

Does anyone know what library this file is from and how I can install in on my system?

**EDIT**: the version of the **gprestore** differs to the version of the **gpbackup** used prior; not sure if that could play a role?

gpbackup version = 1.20.4

gprestore version = 1.30.3

**EDIT 2**: I've downgraded **gprestore** to the same version used to make the backup; I still get the same error, so I doubt that this is a factor.

gpbackup version = 1.20.4

gprestore version = 1.20.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the response below from someone on another forum. It does not resolve my issue, but explains why I'm getting the error.

> gpfmt_gpss is an extension of gp-streaming-server (gpss).  here is the
> doc link
> https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum-Streaming-Server/index.html
> gpss is not open-source, and can only be used by customers who buy
> licenses. If you install gpss, the extension gpss will automatically
> installed in the path of gpdb.